# Why doesn't my Tasks start running unless I call Task.WhenAll()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the code below. (Ignore internal specifics of `FindPhysicalPdfTicketAsync`, internally it contains await/awaitable)

```
IEnumerable<Task> findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks = irTable.ToList().Select(row =>
{
    return FindPhysicalPdfTicketAsync(row,
        ticketListUserControl.physicalPdfTicketExistsStatus);
});
```

Unless I call `Task.WhenAll(findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks)` or `await Task.WhenAll(findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks)` on a line after the above code, the Tasks in the enumerable never execute.

As a test, I ran the `FindPhysicalPdfTicketAsync` method standalone outside of the enumeration, and the Task executed fine.

e.g.

```
IEnumerable<Task> test = irTable.First();

FindPhysicalPdfTicketAsync(test, ticketListUserControl.physicalPdfTicketExistsStatus);
```

So, why does the enumerable one need `Task.WhenAll`?

---

**Update:** My question got closed before I posted my follow up:

Then what causes `Task.WhenAll(findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks)` to trigger enumeration? My understanding is that all `WhenAll()` does is wait for all the "supposedly already running" task to complete.

Comment: Add `ToList` and the end of the returned statement after `Select`, so your enumeration is materialized. Otherwise it is lazily evaluated.

Comment: Because of deferred execution.

Comment: `Select()` only returns a projection promise, it doesn't execute the expression within until you enumerate its results.

Comment: Two things. 1. I know about the lazy/deferred behavior. I was looking at my code's irTable.ToList() part and thinking that, that should have already caused enumeration. It didn't dawn on me that I needed to have another .ToList to trigger enumeration "again" of the select statement. My fault I missed that.

Comment: 2.  Then what causes Task.WhenAll(findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks) to trigger enumeration? My understanding is that all WhenAll() does is wait for all the "supposedly already running" task to complete.

Comment: K.Carter Sr. the `Task.WhenAll` when supplied with an `IEnumerable<Task>` argument, materializes instantly the enumerable by enumerating it, and stores the materialized tasks into a `List<Task>`. You can study its source code [here](https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/Task.cs.html#69351c6da968e5d1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LINQ `.Select()` creates an IEnumerable object. But that object *does not execute its body statement* **until** you ask it to provide you with results.

To get the results, and to make it execute the body statement, you need to **enumerate** the IEnumerable. This can be done in various ways, such as:

```
var taskList = findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks.ToList();
```

or

```
var taskArray = findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks.ToArray();
```

or

```
foreach (var task in findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks)
{
    // ...
}
```

or (as you already did):

```
await Task.WhenAll(findPhysicalPdfTicketTasks);
```